# Detect based on screen resize (instead of page refresh)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Used below HTML for container.

1. If screen size greater than 768... two column layout
2. If screen size lesser than 767... Accordion effect.

By below JS code works fine if we kept screen lesser than 767 and refresh the page. But, i need a solution to work based on screen resize from big screen to smaller screen.

Please let me know solution.

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row" id="accordion">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <h6 class="accordion-toggle">Frequently Ask Questions</h6>
      <ul class="accordion-content default">
        <li> <a href="">Carry with me?</a></li>
        <li> <a href="">Destination country?</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <h6 class="accordion-toggle">Corporate Info</h6>
      <ul class="accordion-content">
        <li> <a href="">Careers</a></li>
        <li> <a href="">Press Room</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**JS:**

```
if ($(window).width() < 767) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
        //Expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
        //Hide the other panels
        $('.accordion-content').not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    });
}
```

Comment: Add a `$(window).resize(callback)` listener.

Comment: Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) not Javascript for this

Comment: not all browsers support media-queries. Some corporate computers still run on winxp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your code inside a window.resize event like @karthnik VU said

Updated

```js
$('#accordion.small').on('click', '.accordion-toggle', function() {
  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
  //Hide the other panels
  $('.accordion-content').not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
});

function resizer(){ 
    $('#accordion').toggleClass('small' , $(window).width() < 767);
    if ($(window).width() >= 767) { 
      $("#accordion").find('.accordion-content').show();
    }
}

$(window).on('resize', resizer).resize();
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your comments. Not sure what happens. After adding your solution, when i click 'accordion-toggle'.. it open/close multiple times and stops after 8 - 10 seconds. Similar behavior on other accordion contents as well.

Comment: ok, updated the code. what happening was, when you resize window, it was adding a new click handler because we have click handler inside resize event. I think updated way, it has a better way to do it.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your update.. now what happens means.. once user moved from 767 to bigger screen, still accordion effect exists. Whatever accordion opened, it will open. Other accordion contents are closed even after 767 screen resolution. Please let me know how to clear the state. Thanks

Comment: ok updated the code to respond to screen size larger than 767px.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly almost all of that could be achieved with css.Apparently you're using bootstrap so you could use some [visibility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to show/hide on certain window sizes. Also, you can check the [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) example of having different looks for different screen sizes. Just resize the page to see. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need a resize listener and need to detect when the user changes from big to small and from small to big screen. I didn't test my code but it might look like this:

```
var lastWindowWidth;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
      var $window = $(this),
          windowWidth = $window.width();

      if (windowWidth < 767 && lastWindowWidth>=768) {

        //accordionify

      } else if (windowWidth >= 768 && lastWindowWidth < 767) {

        //remove accordion
      }

      lastWindowWidth = windowWidth;
    });
});
```

But I think you could achieve this behavior also using plain css (bootstrap helper classes)